# Is there any chance to return ability to make question or should i open a new account

Tags: support

My account is blocked  , so I can't make any question anymore.
Is there any chance to be unblocked or I just should open a new account ?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than trying to evade the block, you should consider *why* you're blocked. The automated post bans start after you create too many poorly-received questions, i.e. questions that are off-topic or not fit for the Q&A format. **Deleted questions count**, and count heavily against you.

I noticed that you don't have the Informed badge, so I will direct you to [the tour](https://superuser.com/tour). Please also look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), both from the [help center](https://superuser.com/help), which would be good to look through.

You can save yourself by editing your existing questions into shape, polishing up their presentiation (formatting and grammar). If you can find your now-deleted questions - there should be a link somewhere in your profile, visible only to you and moderators - undelete them if possible (doable only if you deleted them yourself) and improve them.

**Opening a new account will not help.** The system is smart enough to know when someone's trying to avoid a post ban.

Comment: "polishing up their presentiation" - e.g. spelling :-p

Comment: This site is becoming very censured. A lot's of comments that are presenting true things about how this site works, are deleted because a group of moderators and other VIP users don't like them. And to hide the real reason for deletion ,  these comments  are called " off topic ".

Comment: @alex Extended comment exchanges look really messy, so I can understand why people like to clean them up. In this case, I think it would have been better to move them to chat so there's a record; some useful things were said.

Comment: @alex - The only reason our comments would have been deleted is because I flagged them for removal, because they were not constructive, their removal has NOTHING to do with trying to censure you.  Comments are subject to be removed for any reason, at any time, they are not meant for extended discussions.

Comment: @Ramhound   No my friend , the reason that you've removed them , is because with my last comments I've asked to you to show me if 2 phrases were duplicate or not , and of course you didn't know how to respond. These comments are not off topic because we were talking about how most of my questions were wrongly marked as duplicate from you . My questions are duplicate ?? , are you so smart discovering duplicates ? Ok, please tell me if these 2 phrases are duplicate : 1) I'm saying today , you will come with me. 2) I'm saying , today you will come with me .

Comment: @alex Note that neither I nor Ramhound currently have the ability to unilaterally remove comments. A moderator agreed with the flag, and so removed the comments. If you would like some input on how to improve your content, you could also go to one of the two major chatrooms here (*Root Access*, or *Ask a Super User Moderator*); chat works better for these sort of exchanges than do comment chains.